# Why does "lighter" @font-face still appear as the "normal" weight @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use the "lighter" version of my font, but in firefox and chrome it still appears as the "normal" weight.

Here is my font.css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Avenir;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("AvenirLTStd-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: Avenir;
font-weight: bold;
src: url("AvenirLTStd-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: Avenir;
font-weight: lighter;
src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

Here is what I'm using to activate the "lighter" weight on the `H2` in `#home`:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DADAD2;
    font-family: 'Avenir',sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#home .six.columns h2 {
    color: #FAFAFA;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can see what I'm talking about here (just hover over one of the product images):

https://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/

Comment: Changing the `font-weight` value to any of `500`, `600`, `700`, `800`, `900`, and `bold` definitely changes the text. All other values appear as "normal". I'm not saying that's *correct*; I'm just adding some extra detail.

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen Are you speaking about on my website? I know its really weird because the "lighter" value should change the text to the thinner font variation.

Comment: I agree. I was confirming and adding some extra detail in the hopes that it might be useful to someone else.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627810/chrome-19-not-recognising-font-weight-lighter. Unfortunately, using `100` solved that problem, which it doesn't here. Are you sure the font in question has a lighter version?

Comment: I still have no idea why it was happening, but I've come up with a hackey solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a little hack that differentiates between the lighter and normal font weights.

I just changed my Avenir lighter `@font-face` from:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: lighter;
    src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirLight;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

For some reason it was using the "lighter" font weight for `normal` and `lighter`. After I made this change the `normal` Avenir started using the real normal weight, and when I want to use the `lighter` weight I just change the font-family to `AvenirLight`

Comment: This is a trick that you may need to use to get light typeface, depending on font family and browser. You are effectively declaring a typeface as if it were a font family (and use a “normal” typeface of that “family”). FontSquirrel does this all the time in its font generator. Consider reporting this to the font vendor; the causes of this problem are obscure and might depend on font file format. In any case, when trying use `font-weight`, use the numeric value given by the font vendor, not the relative keyword `lighter`.

Comment: Hi. Pretty same issue here, but with a different font. I used `font-weight: lighter` as well and it basically overwrites my second definition for `font-weight: normal`. Fix is to use the numeric values. Then all is fine. In this sense, I confirm the very last statement of @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: This is not consistent solution, see other answer.

Answer (score 15):

`font-weight: lighter` is telling the browser to use a lighter font than an inherited weight. So if a parent element has `font-weight: bold`, and it's child has `font-weight: lighter` - the child will have a regular weight (i.e. lighter than bold).
"lighter" is *not* a synonym for a font-weight of 100.

`@font-face` is used to define your font weights, so terms like 'bolder' and 'lighter' have no meaning. You should use numerical values to define your fonts and the lighter/bolder keywords when you want to use the fonts.

Comment: Wonderful explanation!, thanks to you I finally was able to understand what was happening.

Comment: What the H$@L :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep the font-family consistent, in this case 'Avenir' and not 'Avenir-light' you can use the following syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url("12-Avenir-Light.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

This syntax allows you to keep the font-family name consistent and the normal weight will display correctly. The CSS for the target element would then be:

```
.targetElement{
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more consistent solution.